# How to specify an IP address with Django test client?

Tags: django, django-testing

I am testing an API with Django test client. The API uses geo blocking so in my test I need to specify an IP address to make sure it works properly. How can I do that?

I am making a request in my test like this:

```
from django.test.client import Client as HttpClient
.
.
.
client = HttpClient()
response = client.get(uri + query_string)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The [`Client.get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.get) method has an `extra` keyword arguments parameter, which can be used to specify headers.

```
c.get(/my-url/, REMOTE_ADDR="127.0.0.1")
```

Answer (score 11):

Pass REMOTE_ADDR in constructor.

```
client = HttpClient(REMOTE_ADDR='127.0.0.1')
```

or

```
client.get('/path/', {'param':'foo'}, **{'HTTP_USER_AGENT':'firefox-22', 'REMOTE_ADDR':'127.0.0.1'})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also set it for all future requests:

```
client.defaults['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '1.2.3.4'
```

Also with subclassing:

```
class DecoratedApiClient(Client):
    def set_ip_addr(self, ip_addr):
        self.defaults['REMOTE_ADDR'] = ip_addr

client = DecoratedApiClient()
client.set_ip_addr('1.2.3.4')
```

Answer (score -2):

As simple like this:

```
client_address = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR') or request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. This is a way to check the header, not to set it in the test client.

Thank you for reminding me I had to check HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR, however :)

Comment: Does not answer the question.